# Need to Increase the Page Number columnwise Rather than Page wise in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

There is a situation for which i have divided my page into two columns. I want pageNumber to be incremented and starting from 1. For an example first page should have 1,2 and second page 3, 4 and so on. Please tell me how i can manipulate the pagenumber field.

Answer (score 2):

You can create new variable for counting number of columns.

The variable definition can be like this:

***Name***: *variable*
***Increment Type***: *Column*
***Calculation***: *Count*
***Reset type***: *Report*
***Expression***: *$V{variable} + 1*
***Initial value expression***: *0*

The sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport .. columnCount="2" .. isFloatColumnFooter="true">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT id, city, street FROM address]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="CITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="STREET" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="columnsCount" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Column" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{columnsCount} + 1]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <detail>
        <band height="63" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="48" height="63"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="48" y="0" width="100" height="63"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="148" y="0" width="128" height="63"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{STREET}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="50">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="156" y="30" width="80" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{columnsCount}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="236" y="30" width="40" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{columnsCount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be:

[image: The preview in iReport]

Comment: Hi Alex. Thank you so much. It works. I need to start it from 1 Rather than 0. I changed the initial value expression to 1. it did not work. How can i achieve this/

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot the first value will be 1. Is it ok for you?

Comment: Thanks Mate. The Evaluation Time must be set to Column. Then Only It will work. Thanks for your help